# SVG group child doesn't transform as expected

Tags: html, css, svg

I would like to translate the `g` element on the X-axis by 100px then rotate it by 45deg over its center
but I get this weird result

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.rotate-translate {
  transform: translate(100px, 0) rotateZ(45deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 200 200" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g class="rotate-translate">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Here I start with rotateZ

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.rotate-translate {
  transform: rotateZ(45deg) translate(100px, 0);
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 200 200" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g class="rotate-translate">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Update**

Seems like the problem doesn't occur in firefox but occurs on chrome. Also if you use the chrome console to remove a CSS propriety then return it to the `rotate-translate` class the `g` element renders in its right position

Comment: Is this: `transform:  translate(100px, 0) rotateZ(45deg)` giving you the expected result?

Comment: @enxaneta shouldn't the order have any importance in case of `transform-origin: center;`?

Comment: no, the order is always important whataver the origin

Comment: @TemaniAfif I forget `transform-box: fill-box;` needs to be too. in this case, the order shouldn't have importance because the element rotates on itself

Comment: Looks like the latest Chrome, that has just been released (84), no longer has this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm... it looks like a potential bug in Chrome.  It doesn't correctly handle `transform-box` on group elements.  If you target the `rect` instead, it worrks correctly.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.rotate-translate rect {
  transform: translate(100px, 0) rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 200 200" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g class="rotate-translate">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

If, for some reason, you *really* need to style the group, then a workaround is to use absolute coordinates in your `transform-origin`.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.rotate-translate {
  transform: translate(100px, 0) rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 200 200" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g class="rotate-translate">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. I absolutly need to rotate the group element because I make 4 copies of a group while rotating each copy to make new svg

Comment: I just discovered that the bug only affects `fill-box`.  If you use `transform-box: stroke-box` it works. So that is another possible workaround that you could use.

Comment: Bug reported to Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1106055

Answer (score 0):

you mean this ?

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  fill:red;
}

.rotate-translate {
  transform: translate(50px, 50px) rotateZ(45deg) ;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewbox="0 0 200 200" >
  <g class="rotate-translate">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
  </g>
</svg>
```